# vba type mismatch on my script

Tags: vba, ms-word, type-mismatch

So, I'm getting a type mismatch in the VBA script of a Word document, however there isn't any line signaled on the editor... Can any of you give me an hint of what it might be?

```
Private Sub bt_run_Click()
'set months array
Dim months As Variable
months = Array("Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro")


With ThisDocument.Tables(0)

Do While .Rows.Count > 2
    .Rows(2).Delete
Loop


'Ask for year
Dim req As String
Dim yr As Integer
req = InputBox("Insere ano.")

If IsNumeric(req) Then
    yr = CInt(req)
Else
    MsgBox ("Erro")
    Return
End If


'get previous year last week
'TODO

'Now generate current year months
For i = 1 To 12
    'get number of mondays on the month (how many weeks belong here)
    Dim mondays As Integer
    mondays = MondaysOnMonth(i, yr)

    'now generate a line for each monday
    For k = 1 To mondays

        .Rows.Add

    Next k

Next i

'get next year first week
'TODO

End With


End Sub


Function MondaysOnMonth(ByVal month As Integer, ByVal year As Integer) As Integer
Dim mondays As Integer
mondays = 0

Dim d As Date
Dim dtStr As String
dtStr = "1/" & month & "/" & year

d = DateValue(dtStr)

Dim days As Integer
days = dhDaysInMonth(d)

For i = 1 To days

    dtStr = i & "/" & month & "/" & year
    d = DateValue(dtStr)
    Dim w As Integer
    w = Weekday(d, vbMonday)

    If w = 0 Then
        mondays = mondays + 1
    End If

Next i
MondaysOnMonth = mondays

End Function

Function dhDaysInMonth(Optional ByVal dtmDate As Date = 0) As Integer
' Return the number of days in the specified month.
If dtmDate = 0 Then
    ' Did the caller pass in a date? If not, use
    ' the current date.
    dtmDate = Date
End If
dhDaysInMonth = DateSerial(year(dtmDate), _
 month(dtmDate) + 1, 1) - _
 DateSerial(year(dtmDate), month(dtmDate), 1)
End Function
```

This pretty much generates how many lines as there're mondays in the entire year in the only table of the document.

I'm not really experienced in all this thing of Visual Basic for Applications, but I'm assuming it's some type casting that the compiler can't execute, however, I can't really see what it might be (and the compiler isn't giving me the necessary help), so what might it be?

Comment: Did you try F8?  Step-though?

Comment: Nope, but tried it now, and it's when I assign the Array into the months variable... Shouldn't the Variable type be like a dynamic variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my (limited) experience, arrays are setup a little differently in VBA:

```
'set months array
Dim months(11) As String
months(0) = "Janeiro"
months(1) = "Fevereiro"
months(2) = "Março"
months(3) = "Abril"
months(4) = "Maio"
months(5) = "Junho"
months(6) = "Julho"
months(7) = "Agosto"
months(8) = "Setembro"
months(9) = "Outubro"
months(10) = "Novembro"
months(11) = "Dezembro"
```

Also, I could not address table 0, so changed it to table 1 and the code seemed to execute.

```
With ThisDocument.Tables(1)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. And yeah, I also found out that these collections are indexed at 1, and not at 0...

Answer (score 0):

Array Function
Returns a Variant containing an array!!!
Dim months As Variant

Answer (score 0):

You were so close.

In your original code, you should be able to change `Variable` to `Variant` and the initialization will work as you expected.

Here I've copy/pasted your array initialization, swapped in `Variant`, and written a loop that confirms the array was properly initialized by printing the values to the Immediate Window (press `Ctrl+G` to view if it is not already visible):

```
Sub TestMonthArrayInitialization()

    Dim months As Variant
        months = Array("Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro")

    Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To 11
            Debug.Print months(i)
        Next i

End Sub
```